# Ajax post returns multiple arrays with objects that have multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a php file that gets messages from a database (ajax.php) and a javascript file that makes ajax request to that ajax.php file (main.js).

What I want: When the php is responding multiple times, the js file would make a table row for every one of them.

main.js:

```
function doAjax(variable) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php"
        data: { content: variable },
        dataType: 'JSON',            
        success: function (response) {
            response.forEach(function(data) {
              $(".messages-table").append("<tr><th>"+from+"</th><th>"+text+"</th><th>"+date+"</th><th>"+num+"</th></tr>")
            })
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php

...

foreach ($messages as $message) {
    $from = $message['contact_value'];
    $text = $message['message'];
    $date = $message['date'];
    $num = $user['phone_number'];
    echo json_encode(array("from"=>"$from", "text"=>"$text", "date"=>"$date", "num"=>"$num"));
?>
```

But when i do that I get this error in developer console:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Qb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Cheers

Comment: Include errors **as text**, copied-and-pasted. Not as images.

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that the JSON started with `<`, which of course it can't. So you need to look at the response and see why that is (odds are it's an error page).

Comment: Side note: Don't do `"from"=>"$from"` ... but rather just `"from"=>$from` etc.

Comment: You can't echo inside the loop. You need to create one array that contains sub arrays and echo the json encoded outer array once after the loop is done

Comment: Side side note: You never define `from` `text` `date` and `num` vars inside the `response.forEach` js code. Those should be more like `data.from` etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your ajax.php should be like this

```
<?php


  foreach ($messages as $message) {
    $from = $message['contact_value'];
    $text = $message['message'];
    $date = $message['date'];
    $num = $user['phone_number'];
    echo json_encode(array("from"=>$from, "text"=>$text,"date"=>$date,"num"=>$num));
?>
```

if you really want the quotes then use ' ' (singlequotes) instead.

And the javascript file.

```
 success: function (response) {
  var success = $.parseJSON(response);
  $(".messages-table").append("<tr><th>"+success.from+"</th><th>"+success.text+"</th><th>"+success.date+"</th><th>"+success.num+"</th></tr>");
}
```

i think you don't need to use the forech loop if you call the doAjax function every time.